# how to pass the value '4' in the parameter 'y' insyead of x in the third constructor call? If it is possible then please tell the answer

Tags: c++

how to pass the value '4' in the parameter 'y' insyead of x in the third constructor call? If it is possible then please tell the answer.

```
#include<iostream>

class Test // class created
{   
    int a,b,sum; 
    public:
    Test(int x=0,int y=0) // constructor created
    {
        a=x;
        b=y;
        sum= a+b;
        cout<<"X="<<x<<"\t"<<"Y="<<y<<"\t"<<"Sum ="<<sum<<"\n";
    }
};

void main()
{
    Test t1; // constructor calling without any values
    Test t2(2,4); // same as above but with two values
    Test t3(4); // it is only with a single value
    getch();
}
```

> how to pass '4' in 'y' instead of 'x' in 3rd object creation?

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: isnt it there any way to alter the passing mehcnism

Comment: It depends on what your real problem is, not for what you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Just call it like
Test t4(0,4);

Comment: u cannot do that. you have to pass single argument.

Answer (score 1):

Use *named* constructor

```
class Test
{   
    int a, b, sum; 
public:
    Test(int x = 0, int y = 0) : a(x), b(y), sum(a + b)
    {
        std::cout << "X=" << x << "\tY=" << y << "\tSum =" << sum << "\n";
    }

    static Test TestY(int y) { return Test(0, y); }
};

int main()
{
    Test t3 = Test::TestY(4);
}
```

or tag constructor

```
struct tagY{};

class Test
{   
    int a, b, sum; 
public:
    Test(int x = 0, int y = 0) : a(x), b(y), sum(a + b)
    {
        std::cout << "X=" << x << "\tY=" << y << "\tSum =" << sum << "\n";
    }

    Test(tagY, int y) : Test(0, y) {}
};

int main()
{
    Test t3(tagY{}, 4); // it is only with a single value
}
```

Comment: thanx for help.

Answer (score 0):

Create 3 constructors, and no default values, java-style

sample code:

```
#include<iostream>    
using namespace std;

class Test
{
    public:
    int sum,a,b;

Test(int x,int y) // constructor created
{
    a=x;
    b=y;
    sum= a+b;
    cout<<"X="<<x<<"\t"<<"Y="<<y<<"\t"<<"Sum ="<<sum<<"\n";
}
Test(int y) : Test(0,y) {}  // constructor created
Test() : Test(0,0) {} // constructor created
};

int main()
{
     Test t1; // constructor calling without any values
    Test t2(2,4); // same as above but with two values
    Test t3(4); // it is only with a single value
    return 0;
}
```

build with: `g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp`

result:

```
X=0     Y=0     Sum =0
X=2     Y=4     Sum =6
X=0     Y=4     Sum =4
```

Alternate pre-C++11 method: use an inlined helper method, maybe even faster.

```
#include<iostream>    
using namespace std;

class Test
{
    public:
    int sum,a,b;

Test(int x,int y) // constructor created
{
    build(x,y);
}
Test(int y) { build(0,y); }  // constructor created
Test() { build(0,0); } // constructor created

private:
inline void build(int x,int y)
{
    a=x;
    b=y;
    sum= a+b;
    cout<<"X="<<x<<"\t"<<"Y="<<y<<"\t"<<"Sum ="<<sum<<"\n";
}
};

int main()
{
     Test t1; // constructor calling without any values
    Test t2(2,4); // same as above but with two values
    Test t3(4); // it is only with a single value
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you just can't, as everyone said. In python or Ada you could, but not here.

Comment: okkzzz so is there any way to alter passing mechanism in c++?

Comment: Is there any way to do it in older version of complier like Turboc++ or dosbox??? 
But i really like ur answer. i think this might be the one which i am luking for.

Comment: yeah i got the concept what you are trying to do. You are checking what kind of arguments is there and and then calling it suitable constructor. 
i guess i'll try yr last edit and yeah thanx for ur help.

Comment: on e more thing is there any way to directly pass it to parameter y using one constructor or function?

Answer (score 0):

If you want 'y' to be passed as parameter when Test object's constructor is called with 1 argument, change the order of arguments in constructor definition

```
Test(int y=0, int x=0)
{ /*--- */}
```

Comment: the order had to be this. the thihng is this we need to pass it to the trailing argument.

Comment: It is not possible to specify 'only' trailing argument if there are default arguments before it.
Think for a minute, how would you call the constructor while only specifying 'x', and not 'y'?

Comment: yeah. tht is the problem is what i m facing.

Comment: You can create multiple constructors. Since named parameters are not an option in C++, you have to do this in one of the ways suggested here

Answer (score -2):

The above answer answers your question. But, if you want a constructor that takes only 1 argument, you could use polymorphism and create another constructor.

```
#include<iostream>

class Test // class created
{   
    int a,b,sum; 
    public:
    Test(int x=0,int y=0) // constructor created
    {
        a=x;
        b=y;
        sum= a+b;
        cout<<"X="<<x<<"\t"<<"Y="<<y<<"\t"<<"Sum ="<<sum<<"\n";
    }

    Test(int y=0) // another constructor
    {
        a=0;
        b=y;
        sum= a+b;
        cout<<"X="<<x<<"\t"<<"Y="<<y<<"\t"<<"Sum ="<<sum<<"\n";
    }
};

void main()
{
    Test t1; // constructor calling without any values
    Test t2(2,4); // same as above but with two values
    Test t3(4); // it is only with a single value
    getch();
}
```

Comment: the second constructor would b similar like passing test t3(4) as t3(0,4)

Comment: yup. but it is cleaner. what exact behaviour do you need?

Comment: can't work: call of overloaded 'Test(int)' is ambiguous because of default values.

Comment: what i want is to go the argument into parameter y with only single constructor if this is possible.

Comment: oh shit. yes. dammit. thanks for pointing that out. I dont know what i was thinking. XD

Comment: i tried mostly all the things except the above answer of Jean-farncois Fabre. nothing happens to work .

Comment: The way I see it, you could reverse the order of the arguments like kaustubh's answer or do it without default arguments like Jean's answer. Doing this with a single constructor is not possible.

Comment: yeah reversing i tried but yeah i have to try the jean answer. i guess i'll try if nothing happens then i'll come back.

Comment: @ch941g that's not polymorphism that's (failed) overloading.

Comment: How is it like this?